# UIImageView animation loops with different speeds

Tags: iphone, animation, uiimageview

I've got an array with several images that I'm adding into an UIImageView:

```
myImageView.animationImages = myArrayOfImages;
```

Now, I want to execute that loop of images X times, but each one with a different duration

```
myImageView.animationDuration = randomTime;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried? I believe you will need to create a new instance of the UIImageView each time.

Comment: Will that be transparent for the user? I want to show the same animation many times but with different durations. Creating new instance of the UIImageViews could produce some kind of short interruptions, am I right?

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. You would create your UIImage objects at start and not delete those - you would just re-use the UIImage objects each time you create a UIImageView. I am not suggesting re-loading the images each time, just recreating the UIImageView that uses them.

Comment: And what about `[self performSelector:@selector(animationDone) withObject:nil afterDelay:X];` and in `animationDone` modify the duration and call `startAnimating` again?

Comment: Having just looked at the docs I think that will probably work fine. I'm surprised you haven't tried already, lol.